# Using one input form and using localStorage on 2 buttons

Tags: javascript, html, button, local-storage, form-submit

I've tried to use different class names/key names it still won't pull any data to localStorage for the liked2.on("click", saveData).. do I need to incorporate a for loop of some sort so it passes through both buttons?

** note the local storage does work on the liked1.on("click", saveData) **

```html
        <form id="form1">
          <label>
            <h4>Destination One</h4>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="cityName"
              placeholder="Enter a destination"
              id="input"
            />
          </label>
          <button type="submit" class="primary button search-button">
            search
          </button>
          <div type="button" class="button button-like" id="liked1">
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
          </div>
        </form>
```

```js
  function saveData() {
    var cities = document.getElementById("input").value;
    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(cities));
    var savedCity = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));

    localStorage.setItem("list", JSON.stringify(savedCity));
    var result = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("list"));
    console.log(result);
  }

  liked1.on("click", saveData);
  liked2.on("click", saveData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't clearly understand what do you want to do, so I will try my best to answer your question.

Every time you use `setItem` with the same `keyName`, it overrides the old one and fill it with the new one.

So you can

- Use different `keyNames` for each form, for example, `form1_cityName` for the first form and `form2_cityName` for the second form
- Change the format you save data in `setItem`, like JSON